# Cannot read property 'modalIsOpen' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I want to iterate over few data with [react-modal](https://github.com/rackt/react-modal) then populate those data into a modal when a button is clicked, It pops up different values based on which button is clicked. Hope this make sense? If not:

I'm iterating over few data so in each loop, I'll have a button. When I click on button one, I get some value. When I click on button two, I get different value but not same as button one's value.

```
var React = require('react');
var Modal = require('react-modal');

Cards = React.createClass({

getInitialState:function(){
      return{
          filteredData: this.props.data, // Im using react-rails to get this 'data'
          modalIsOpen: false
      }
  },

  openModal: function() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
  },

  closeModal: function() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  },

  handleModalCloseRequest: function() {
    // opportunity to validate something and keep the modal open even if it
    // requested to be closed
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  },

  handleInputChange: function() {
    this.setState({foo: 'bar'});
  },

render(){
 var cards=[];
 this.props.data.slice(0, 25).forEach(function(s) {
 cards.push(
  <div key={s.id}>
    <button className="button tiny radius" onClick={this.openModal}>view</button>
    <Modal
      closeTimeoutMS={150}
       isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
       onRequestClose={this.handleModalCloseRequest}>
       <h1>{s.title}</h1>
       <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
        <div>{s.description}</div>
         <form>
          <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
          <input />
          <br/>              
          <button>{s.agree}</button>
         </form>
     </Modal>
  </div>
 )
 });

 return(
  {cards}
 )
}

});
module.exports = Cards;
```

If I move `<Modal></Modal>` into the `render()` all works well but I need the loop of the modal. Is there a way to rewrite this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first create a state `currentData` so I can move `<Modal />` away from the `loop`.

```
getInitialState:function(){
    return{
        filteredData: this.props.data,
        modalIsOpen: false,
        currentData: {}
    }
},
```

I will then create a separate function to create the content of the modal, I will call it `renderModalContent`.

```
renderModalContent: function(s) {
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>{s.title}</h1>
          <div>{s.description}</div>
          <form>
              <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
              <button>{s.agree}</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    )
},
```

this will be the loop inside your `render` method

```
    var cards = this.props.data.slice(0,25).map( (s, i) => {
        return (
            <div key={s.id}>
                <button className="button tiny radius" onClick={this.openModal.bind(this,s)}>View</button>
            </div>
        );
    });
```

You can see that I'm binding `this.openModal` with `this`. You `openModal` is

```
openModal: function(s) {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true, currentData: s});
},
```

and it's using `this.setState` hence the binding.
The `s` is the argument I'm passing to the `renderModalContent` function so we can pass it to `this.setState({currentData})`.

This will be the return value of your `render` method

```
    var currentData = this.state.currentData;
    return(
        <div>
            { cards }                
            <Modal
                closeTimeoutMS={150}
                isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
                onRequestClose={this.handleModalCloseRequest}>
                {
                    Object.keys(currentData).length > 0 ?
                      this.renderModalContent(currentData) :
                      null;
                }
                <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
            </Modal>
        </div>
        })
    )
```

Edit: Removed `bind` as @Alexander and @Sylar suggested in the comments

Comment: Hi Road. React complains about `Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.` But when I remove the bind, values not passing to the modal.

Comment: Remove the bind from `renderModalContent:` and all is well. Thanks!

Comment: @Road you don't need use bind if you are using React.createClass

Comment: @Alexander didn't know that. been using `class` ever since. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your code now there are couple errors

**1** Component must have only one root element., you should wrap `cards` to element

```
return (<div>
   {cards}
</div>);
```

**2** in `.forEach` `this` refers to global scope, but not to `Cards` `Object` ,. you should set `this` `forEach`, however in this case you can use `.map` it is more suitable, and you can set `this` just pass second argument, like this

```
var cards = this.props.data.slice(0, 25).map(function(s) {
   // code ...
   // now this refers to Carts Object
}, this);
--^^^^^--
```

*Example*

```
var Cards = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return{
      filteredData: this.props.data,
      modalIsOpen: false,
      modalData: {}
    }
  },

  openModal: function(data) {
    this.setState({
       modalData: data
    });
  },

  closeModal: function() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  },

  handleModalCloseRequest: function() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  },

  handleInputChange: function() {
    this.setState({foo: 'bar'});
  },

  render()  {
    var cards = this.props.data.slice(0, 25).map(function(s) {
      return (<div key={ s.id }>
        <button className="button tiny radius" 
            onClick={this.openModal.bind(this, s)}>view</button>
        <Modal closeTimeoutMS={150} 
            isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen} 
            onRequestClose={this.handleModalCloseRequest}>
          <h1>{s.title}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
          <div>{s.description}</div>
          <form>
            <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            <input />
            <br />
            <button>{s.agree}</button>
          </form>
        </Modal>
      </div>)
    }, this);

    return (<div>
      {cards}
    </div>);
  }
});
```